# Printing A JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, swing, printing, javafx

I've looked around but can't find any tutorials as to how to go about Printing a JavaFX 2.0 WebView. Anyone with real world experience for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly easy to use the following approach:

- Capture the WebView as an image
- Print the image using any of Java's standard printing services.

This [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_printing) links to some useful details on how to do this.

Comment: I've seen that post previously but it does not mention WebView specifically so not sure it may solve the problem. I'll give it a go though and see how it turns out.