# How to print the content of a JavaFx 2 WebView

Tags: java, javafx, printing, webview, javafx-2

I was using JavaFx 8 previously, but it has dropped support for Windows XP SP2, and as a result I have had to downgrade my JavaFx version to JavaFx 2. Before the downgrade I was able to print webview content, but I do not seem to be able to do that anymore with JavaFx 2. How do I print the content of a WebView using JavaFx 2?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/webview/printing.htm

Comment: I am not using javafx 8.I am trying it from javafx2

Comment: In Javafx2 webview dosn't support printing. Perhaps ypu can use http://www.printhtml.com/

Comment: You can still us Java 8, [see here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21202600/2855515)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing A JavaFX WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280656/printing-a-javafx-webview)